# How can I remove GRUB2 entries in Fedora 16?

Tags: fedora, grub2

Recently, I executed the following command:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Now I have 6-7 Linux entries + 1 windows entry.
How do I remove older kernel entries?

I don't want to remove all the recovery kernel options by using:

```
GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_RECOVERY="true"
```

Comment: Any reason not to just comment out the ones you don't want?

Comment: If your distribution auto generates the grub config, the easiest thing to do is to uninstall the older kernels.

Comment: @Kevin is right, just comment out the ones you don't want in `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`.  The way these scripts work you get an entr

Comment: @Kevin : Thanks for improving the question. I don't mind commenting out unwanted entries but which file should I edit? /etc/grub.cfg suggests that it is autogenerated & should not be edited.

Comment: @sr_ : It says 'DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE'. I commented the unwanted entries but isn't there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` is generated automatically by the `grub2-mkconfig` command, which will be run automatically when a new kernel is installed.  This command iterates over available  kernel packages on your system.  Attempts to directly edit this file will ultimately fail (because the entries you commented out will simply be regenerated).

As @jw013 says, the easiest solution is to simply remove kernel packages if you don't want to use them anymore.

If you need to edit *options* in this file, you can edit `/etc/default/grub`, which defines shell variables used in the generation scripts.  You can also look in `/etc/grub.d`, which is a collection of shell scripts that are run to generate the configuration.

Comment: I didn't want to mess with the shell scripts so just removed older kernels.

Answer (score 1):

you could just run `package-cleanup --oldkernels`.  There's a lot more options available to that command, just read the manual or execute: `package-cleanup --help`.

Additionally, if you comment out(add # at the beginning) the line `GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"`, it will generate an "Advanced" submenu for the recovery menuentries, etc.  Each OS will be displayed 2; Once for default options, and an additional for "advanced" options.  Your Grub2 menu will look much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora tries to keep 3 kernels around when updating (for the rare case of spectacular fireworks on boot).